# Form won't submit return false;

Tags: jquery, html

My simple form won't submit after the input and textarea have been filled. edited for readability.

```
$(function () {
    $("#contactform").submit(function () {
        $(":input").not("[type=submit]").removeClass('error').each(function () {
            if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0) $(this).addClass('error');

        });            
        if($(document).hasClass("error")){
        return false;
}
    });
});


<form id="contactform" action="success.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name" autofocus >
  <input type="text" placeholder="email" >
  <textarea placeholder="message" ></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
  </input>
</form>
```

Comment: and what do you think is the problem? What have you done to solve it? Can you provide an example on JSfiddle? Can you do more things descript in [ask] to help us answering your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check to see if there are any errors before returning false

```
$(function () {
    $("#contactform").submit(function () {
        $(":input").not("[type=submit]").removeClass('error').each(function () {
            if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0) $(this).addClass('error');    
        });
        // if there is anything with a class of error inside the form
        // can also use $(this).find('.error') - it's the same thing
        if($('.error',this).length){
            // then return false
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D4F55/

Answer (score 1):

You are using `return false;` which prevents submission. Only use that when you want to stop the form from submitting (Eg errors in validation etc )

Answer (score 1):

Do not use return false everytime.

Check if you have inputs with errors like

```
return !!$('input.error').length;
```

Comment: I don't think this is a very readable way of doing it.

Comment: "Is there any input with error"

Comment: It may not be easily readable, however it does work where the original did not.

Answer (score 1):

DO not use `return false;`, That stops the from submission.

Change your code to something like this:

```
    $(function () {
    $("#contactform").submit(function (e) {
        $(":input").not("[type=submit]").each(function () {
            if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){ 
                $(this).addClass('error');
               e.preventDefault(); 
            }

        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Basic point here is that you shall use `return false;`, only when you want to stop the form from getting submitted, and that you may want to do when you feel that the form fields haven't been filled and hence I had it inside `if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){ }` block... rest is upto you to figure out...

Comment: Hah... you had wrong code pasted in your question :|

Comment: This is close, but it stops the code on the first error rather than marking every input that has an error.

Comment: Yup I too noticed that, but thought that this would at least let the form submit.

Comment: doesn't the return false just exit out of the each loop?  http://jsfiddle.net/7cnSM/

Comment: Yes it does and on the way it also stops the form from being submitted.

Comment: @Amar it doesn't.. check the fiddle..  It will only break out of the each loop.. not stop the form from submitting

Comment: [returns inside each loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8224424/1385672)

Comment: oops, my bad.. check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/7cnSM/3/
It's better to use `preventDefault()`