# How it will work when returning a value in .each() function in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, loops, each

Using .each() function, to break out of each() loops, we can use return false.

e.g.

```
$( "div" ).each(function( index, element ) {
     alert('Bye...!');
     return false;
});
```

But, How it will work when returning any string value?

```
var myDiv = $( "div" ).each(function( index, element ) {
     return "xyz";
});
```

Comment: you simply can not return frm each loop... put global element on top and then set value in each loop..

Comment: what are you trying to do

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery each - Stop loop and return object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224375/jquery-each-stop-loop-and-return-object)

Comment: @Juhana: the OP is asking how it will work not *How to break out of .each() and return*

Comment: @TomSarduy How are you going to return a value without breaking out of the loop :)

Comment: @Juhana: That's what the OP want to know ;)

Comment: @Arun I wanted to filter few divs from all divs. I gave that example to understand How returning any constant in each() is working?

Comment: if you are looking to filter some divs from a set then you need to use [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning any constant in .each() loop means returning true.

Also,

```
 var myDiv = $( "div" ).each(function( index, element ) {
                  return "xyz";
             });
```

The above code is equivalent to

```
 var myDiv = $( "div" );
```

Check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/manikanta_ac/8PxVc/)

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer:

`return` won't work this way in `$.each.` return will just exit the foreach loop.

```
var myDiv = $( "div" ).each(function( index, element ) {
     return "xyz";
});
console.log(myDiv);
```

This will output `undefined`. Let's try different things and compare outputs:

#### Long answer

I'm agree that is not clear enough in the [Jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/), they just say: *"You can stop the loop from within the callback function by returning false."* What about returning a variable, or returning true? Let's compare different functions:

```
var stores = ["C", "B", "A"];

function HasC() {
    $(stores).each(function (i, s){
        if(s=="C")
            //yes, we have a C, so let's return true
            return true;
    });
}

function HasB() {
    var b = false;
    $(stores).each(function (i, s){
        if(s=="B"){
            b=true;
            return b;
        }
    });
}

function HasA() {
    var a = false;
    $(stores).each(function (i, s){
        if(s=="A"){
            a = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return a;
}
```

- `HasC()` will return `undefined` after but will iterate all the elements, without break
- `HasB` will return `undefined` as well, because the `b` variable context is just inside the each function.
- `HasA()` will return `true` and work as expected because once we found the "A", we stop the loop using `return false` and then after the loop we still have `var a` alive.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aXkcW/19/

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

```
var myDiv = $( "div" ).map(function( index, element ) {
     return "xyz";
});
```

Returning contant `"XYZ"` does not make much sense to me you proably need to return something else.

> The $.map() method applies a function to each item in an array or
>   object and maps the results into a new array. Prior to jQuery 1.6,
>   $.map() supports traversing arrays only. As of jQuery 1.6 it also
>   traverses objects, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/).

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach to iterate through a set of elements and do some actions on them or from them, but i dont see the point of returning anything since return will break the foreach loop :

```
        $("div").each(function () {
            // update all divs text
            $(this).html = "new text";
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a flag..

see **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GjbNx/1/)**

```
 var flag = false;
 $( "div" ).each(function( index, element ) {     
     if(!flag){
         flag=true;
         alert(index);
         return "xyz";
     }
 });
```