# loop is not breaking when return statement used

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to return an object based on some conditions i.e if some condition is satisfied I want to break the loop and return the object back to the called function.

below is my code.

```
function someFun(that,filterID,columnSelctedID) {
    $.each(that.filters,function(i,filter) {
        if(filter.id==filterID) {
            $.each(filter.filters,function(j,column) {
                if(column.id==$('#' + columnSelctedID + ' .rule-filter-container-column select').val()) {
                    return column;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the if ever runs?

Comment: it would be really helpfull if you can reproduce the issue in a fiddle.

Comment: if(filter.id==filterID), where is filter.id you will get value?

Comment: @nicael yes I can see that the control is coming at line `return column` and proceeding with the loop.

Comment: @WahyuKodar in the $.each u can a find object with name filter which has id property

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224375/jquery-each-stop-loop-and-return-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224375/jquery-each-stop-loop-and-return-object)

Comment: $.each will iterate over each item in the collection whether you return some value or not. What you need is something like Underscore's 'find' method. I don't think jquery has an equivalent to that. If you do not want to use Underscore, then use a vanilla 'for' loop

Comment: FYI, this may be a case where it's a lot simpler to just use a regular `for` loop rather than `$.each()` because then you can just `return column` from anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `return false` to breack `.each` loop. You can use an external variable to assign selected value. Something like this may do the trick

```
function someFun(that,filterID,columnSelctedID) {
    var col; // this is used to hold selected column
    $.each(that.filters,function(i,filter) {
        if(filter.id==filterID) {
            $.each(filter.filters,function(j,column) {
                if(column.id==$('#' + columnSelctedID + ' .rule-filter-container-column select').val()) {
                    col = column;
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return col;
}
```

Comment: but I want to return the column to the called function, of course I can use a global variable but I am not interested to do so

Comment: @user1655222: just added return col to the function. You probably want to add some condition on outer each to make it break too. Maybe checking when changes its default value?