# Javascript not returning in $.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have a function like so:

```
function contains(needle,haystack) {
    return $.each(haystack,function(i,v) {
        if(v == needle) {
            console.log('true, so return');
            return true;
        }
        if(typeof v == 'object') {
            return app.contains(needle,v);
        }
        console.log('I have not yet returned');
        return false;
    });
}
```

When I pass something into it (let's say an object of length 2, with one item matching) the console shows:

```
true, so return
I have not yet returned
I have not yet returned
```

Why is this? How do I fix it?

Comment: I'm confused. Why does the $.each have a return in front? And why does your $.each callback have a return?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224375/jquery-each-stop-loop-and-return-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning true/undefined from the each callback will continue executing the next iteration.

What you need to do is to use a flag and if a match is found then set the flag to true and `return false` so that rest of the iterations will be ignored

```
function contains(needle, haystack) {
    var result = false;
    $.each(haystack, function (i, v) {
        if (v == needle) {
            console.log('true, so return');
            result = true;
            return false;
        }
        if (typeof v == 'object') {
            if (app.contains(needle, v)) {
                result = true;
                return false;
            }
        }
        console.log('I have not yet returned');
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Just remove the return in front of `$.each` and change flag to result then it works perfectly.

Comment: Your `flag` here does nothing. To break loop, you need return `false` (see my answer bellow)

Comment: @ArūnasSmaliukas it was a typo... suppose to be `result = true;`

Answer (score -1):

It is because you return only from inner function of each `$.each` iteration.

To break `$.each` loop you need `return false`, so `return !result` will return `false` if and only if result if found

```
function contains(needle,haystack) {
    var result = false;

    $.each(haystack,function(i,v) {
        if(v == needle) {
            result = true;
            return !result;
        }
        if(typeof v == 'object') {
            result = contains(needle,v);
            return !result;
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8dggq7ds/2/

Or shorter version

```
function contains(needle,haystack) {
    var result = false;

    $.each(haystack,function(i,v) {
        return !(result = (typeof v === 'object') ? contains(needle,v) : v == needle);
    });

    return result;
}
```

Moreover, recursion call `app.contains()` change to `contains()`.