# Function Returns Incorrect Value in the Middle of jQuery Each Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting strange behavior where I want to return immediately in the middle of a jQuery Each Loop, and my expectation is, the function below should return TRUE (the condition matches). But I'm still getting FALSE. This would have worked in Java, but doesn't work in JS/jQuery?

```js
function returnFromLoop(eventIDs) {

   jQuery.each(eventIDs, function(index, item) {
       if (item.indexOf("TEST") != -1) {
           return true;
       }
   
   });
   return false;
}

var eventIDs = [];
eventIDs.push('abc');
eventIDs.push('defTEST');
eventIDs.push('ghi');

var result = returnFromLoop(eventIDs);
console.log('result = ' + result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The `return true;` statement is inside the `.each()` callback function,and it therefore only affects that. It does not return from the outer function.

Comment: and there's no way to force a function-return while keeping this syntax?

Comment: As a side note, you should consider using more modern JS. Browser support is an issue, but the newer Array functions can all be easily polyfilled to provide IE backwards compatibility, even without complicated build chain tools like Babel. You could accomplish the above without jQuery, simply with `return eventIDs.includes(id => item.includes("TEST"))` as the function body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `return true` inside jQuery's `.each()` method does not break out of the loop. Instead you can use `return false` to break out of the loop.

Then, in order to capture the return value, you can use a variable. In the snippet below I have used variable `returnValue`. Once out of the loop, you can return that variable.

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/:

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.

```js
function returnFromLoop(eventIDs) {
  var returnValue = false;
  jQuery.each(eventIDs, function(index, item) {
    if (item.indexOf("TEST") != -1) {
      returnValue = true;
      return false; // Equivalent to break statement.
    }
  });
  return returnValue;
}

var eventIDs = [];
eventIDs.push('abc');
eventIDs.push('defTEST');
eventIDs.push('ghi');

var result = returnFromLoop(eventIDs);
console.log('result = ' + result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks this syntax is too confusing so I'll just rewrite with a For-loop and avoid the jQuery Each.

Comment: @geneb. Do check out [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) - looking at your code, it seems you could use it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to return two functions out so I used an extra variable for solution. `return true` act as a type of continue so you need to return false.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8224424/6517383 will help you understand more.

```js
function returnFromLoop(eventIDs) {
   var state = 0;
   jQuery.each(eventIDs, function(index, item) {
       if (item.indexOf("TEST") != -1) {
            state = 1;
            return 1;
       }
   });
   if(state == 1) {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}

var eventIDs = [];
eventIDs.push('abc');
eventIDs.push('defTEST');
eventIDs.push('ghi');

var result = returnFromLoop(eventIDs);
console.log('result = ' + result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```