# Could not return from if statement using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing one issue. The return statement is not working as expected using Javascript/Jquery. I am explaining my code below.

```
$.each(resultArr,function(i,data){
            console.log('dt',data);
            var rule = $("#sub"+i).val();
            if (rule == '') {
                var subject=data.sub_name;
                toastr.error('Attendance for '+ subject +' can not be blank');
                return false;
            }else if (parseInt(rule) > 100) {
                var subject=data.sub_name;
                toastr.error('Attendance for '+ subject +' can not be more than 100');
                return false;
            }else{
                data.attendance=rule;
                if (data.id == '') {
                    flag=0;
                }else{
                    flag=1;
                }
            }
        })
```

Here I need if `else if` is true it should return after displaying the error message. but in my case its showing the error message and also the `else` part is executing and value is assigning to flag variable. Here I need once error message will display it should return from there.

Comment: The function that returns is the one you define on the first row, inside the `.each`. Do you want the **whole** `each` loop to stop and return?

Comment: yes, I need in that point the loop will stop and return.

Comment: Then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8224424/3103891) is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: As per this link I have used `return false` to stop the loop but same issue.

Comment: How can if and else part execute one after another?

Comment: But its happening.

Comment: It seems your else part is executing in one iteration and then if part in another iteration.

Comment: Lets for 1st iteration `if statement` went false the `else if is executing` if its true,its showing the error message ans next else part is also executing.

Comment: @subhra I have added a below snippet of running code. Please try to run that and check where your expectations are not getting matched?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work: note how the line `console.log('The input is fine')` runs only once.

The only thing I wasn't able to reconstruct was `toastr.error`, so I guess the problem lies somewhere there.

```js
let resultArr = [{
  sub_name: 1
}, {
  sub_name: 2
}];

let ans = null;

$.each(resultArr, function(i, data) {
  console.log('dt', data);
  var rule = $("#sub" + i).val();
  if (rule == '') {
    var subject = data.sub_name;
    ans = ('Attendance for ' + subject + ' can not be blank');
    return false;
  } else if (parseInt(rule) > 100) {
    var subject = data.sub_name;
    ans = ('Attendance for ' + subject + ' can not be more than 100');
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log('The input is fine');
    data.attendance = rule;
    if (data.id == '') {
      flag = 0;
    } else {
      flag = 1;
    }
  }
});

console.log(ans);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="sub0" value="1"></div> - This element's value is valid<br>
<input id="sub1" value="101"></div> - This element's value is invalid
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working very much fine. Adding this as an answer so that you can see answer using Run Code Snippet.

```js
var resultArr = [{
    'sub_name': 'a',
    'id': 1,
    'attendance': ''
  },
  {
    'sub_name': 'b',
    'id': 2,
    'attendance': ''
  },
  {
    'sub_name': 'c',
    'id': 3,
    'attendance': ''
  }
];

function test() {
  $.each(resultArr, function(i, data) {
    console.log('dt', data);
    var rule = $("#sub" + i).val();
    if (rule == '') {
      var subject = data.sub_name;
      //toastr.error('Attendance for ' + subject + ' can not be blank');
      return false;
    } else if (parseInt(rule) > 100) {
      var subject = data.sub_name;
      //toastr.error('Attendance for ' + subject + ' can not be more than 100');
      return false;
    } else {
      data.attendance = rule;
      if (data.id == '') {
        flag = 0;
      } else {
        flag = 1;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="btn btn-primary" onClick="test();"> Call me </a>
<input id="sub0" name="sub0" value="" />
<input id="sub1" name="sub1" value="100" />
<input id="sub2" name="sub2" value="2" />
<input id="sub3" name="sub3" value="4" />
```